# I am trying to make a GUI application using tkinter

Tags: python

I want to make two main function first import from Excel file(.xlsx) to my application and save the imported data to mysql database , second function is to export the file to excel file (.xlsx) after doing some other things to every record

My main problem is:

1. I want to export and import *.xlsx extension  ****not *.csv****.
2. I want to export seperate columns with headings.
3. I dont want to export my data to file of data seperate by comma.
   Edit: what after I import xlsxwriter.
   Note : I don't want to import from mysql I want to import to mysql.

Here is my code:

'''

```
#import all what I need:
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
import mysql.connector as mysql 
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd

# define mydatabase:
db = mysql.connect( host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "S@mY2829", database="sample", auth_plugin="mysql_native_password")
cursor = db.cursor()  

#Global variable:
mydata = []
root = Tk()

#define my fuctions:
#1
def update(records):
  global mydata
  mydata = records
  trv.delete(*trv.get_children())
  for i in records:
     trv.insert('', 'end', values=i)

#2
def clear():
  query = "SELECT * FROM demo"
  cursor.execute(query)
  records = cursor.fetchall()
  update(records)

#3
def import_():
  fln = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Open Window", filetypes=[('ALL Files', '*.xlsx *.xlsm *.sxc *.ods *.csv *.tsv')])
  with open(fln) as myfile:
     csvread = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter=',')
     for i in csvread:
         mydata.append(i)
  update(mydata)
  for i in mydata:
     uid = i[0]
     fname = i[1]
     lname = i[2]
     age = i[3]
     date = i[4]
     query = "INSERT INTO demo(id, first_name, last_name, age, date) VALUES(NULL, %s, %s, %s, NOW())"
     cursor.execute(query, (fname, lname, age))
  db.commit()
  clear()

#4
def export_():
  if len(mydata) < 1:
     messagebox.showerror("Error Window", "No data avaliable to export")
     return False
  fln = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Save Window", filetypes=(("CSV File", "*.csv"),("XLSX File","*.xlsx")))
  with open(fln, mode='w', newline='') as myfile:
     exp_writer = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',')
     for i in mydata:
         exp_writer.writerow(i)
  messagebox.showinfo("Data Exported", "Your data has been exported to "+os.path.basename(fln)+" successfully.")


#section my window:
section1 = LabelFrame(root, text="Customer List Section")
section1.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=20, pady=10)


# define my treeview:
trv= ttk.Treeview(section1, columns=(1,2,3,4,5), show="headings", height="6")
trv.pack()
trv.heading(1, text="ID")
trv.heading(2, text="First Name")
trv.heading(3, text="Last Name")
trv.heading(4, text="Age")
trv.heading(5, text="Date")

#Display the columns in database:
query = "SELECT * from demo" # demo is name of the table
cursor.execute(query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
update(records) 

#make the buttons:
expbtn = Button(section1, text="Export File", command=export_)
expbtn.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)

impbtn = Button(section1, text="Import File", command=import_)
impbtn.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)



root.title("Demo")
root.geometry("2000x1000")
root.mainloop()
```

'''

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want csv, you don't want the csv module. Use `pip` to install the [`xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) module and use that instead.

Comment: and then what? sorry I am new in this

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `sqlalchemy` and `openpyxl` with `pandas`, they are much more simple. Here's how the code which loads data could look lie:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:S@mY2829@localhost/sample')
mydata = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM demo', engine)
```

Then, you could use `mydata.itertuples()` or `mydata.todict()` to populate the screen form.

Saving to Excel is that simple too: `mydata.to_excel(filename, index=False)`. Note that `openpyxl` package has to be installed as it is been used under the hood.

Comment: I don't want to import from my sql i want to import to my sql